# ng build --watch broken re build process

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have fire "**ng build --watch**" command. but, only one time build. not building continue after save.

**My version details:**

```
_                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
node: 6.10.3
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.5
@angular/common: 4.4.5
@angular/compiler: 4.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.5
@angular/core: 4.4.5
@angular/forms: 4.4.5
@angular/http: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-server: 4.4.5
@angular/router: 4.4.5
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.5
typescript: 2.5.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue... this issue found in Linux

At my side, I found the issue: the system that detects changes (inotify) can't handle so much watches by default.
To change the amount of watches it can handle (=the maximum amount of files that will be in the project) you must run this command:

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

**The problem with inotify is reseting this counter every time you restart your computer**.
In the previous version, there was an alert to tell that the whole project couldn't be observed. So we knew we had to run this command. It's not the case anymore.
Something, somehow, somewhere should be done so that this file detection always works out of the box on linux.

More details: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2389#issuecomment-250964095